# interface method for allowing subtype to specify return value

Tags: java, operator-overloading

I have stumbled across a strange concept while creating an API which is equivalent to C++'s operator overloading (just theoretical. It can't actually overload operators but it could be implemented as such).

I have an Interface named `Operatable<T>` (It's more math-based, but that's not important) which implements all of the operators as functions (add, subtract, greater_than, unary minus, increment, etc..).

Only the math operations (+, -, *, /) are required to be implemented and the rest are defaulted to some other value. I'm having an issue implementing the square-bracket operator though, as the return type depends on the subclass and can't be known be the interface at compile-time. I would like to know if it were possible to make the subclass implement it with a specific type or if this is just impossible to do in java.

Thanks for all help!

Edit:
The return type of this function won't necessarily be of the same type as the class itself but should be defined be the subclass

Edit:
I've tried function-bound generics but that doesn't give me the intended result.

Here's an example of the function in a `ComplexDouble` class:

```
public class ComplexDouble extends ComplexNumber<Double> implements Operatable<ComplexDouble> {
    @Override
    public double /*or Double if necessary*/ elementAt (String compName) {
        if (compName.contentEquals("real")) return realComp;
        if (compName.contentEquals("imaginary")) return imagComp;
        throw new NoSuchElementException("The key \"" + compName + "\" is not recognized by " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

This is the overridden function in `Operatable<T>`:

```
public interface Operatable<T> {
    public <K> /*return type here*/ elementAt(K key); // the first generic argument for the parameter works, just not for the return type
    // with the generic type K the subclass can't specify the type (naturally)
}
```

Edit:
I'm not only going for a solution, I'm just curious if this is even possible.

Comment: Do you want that your subclass define the return type of the method? All the methods are intended to return numbers? Do you want to force your subclass to return only numbers?

Comment: No, return type is arbitrary. The subclass should provide the return type of the method as you said.